# ETC Stuck in ETH standard wallet contract

Tags: contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic

I used to use the standard wallet contract in Mist to store ETH and as a result have some ETC still stored in the wallet contract address according to the ETC block explorer. I am trying to figure out how to move the ETC from the contract.

I can access the contact on MEW by switching to ETC mode. Is there a function on the standard wallet contract that can return the ETC to the contract owner address? I have read and I'm not 100% sure the kill function could do this? I want to make sure as I don't want the ETC to be stuck forever. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A contract generally works exactly the same way regardless of what network it's on, so if you have an instance of the same contact on the ETC network, where it contains ETC, the same function call that would move ETH from a contract on the ETH network should move ETC from a contract on the ETC network.

Comment: Doesn't the contract have to be deployed on both chains *and* have the same address for this to work? It may be the case for Mist's contract, but I don't think this is true in general.

Comment: I am not conformable enough using the command line tools to flip parity to the etc chain. (noob, non CS person). What are your thoughts on using the kill command when I have the wallet contact pulled up in MEW. It also has a kill to command. If I entered my main address there and killed the wallet contract would the ETC the wallet contain flow into my (kill to) address? I could then send the ETC through MEW to an exchange

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the ETC from the contact wallet with the kill command. The entire balance reverted back in to the address of the contract creator. I hope this  helps others who were in my position